# How is this C++ code working with an unusual single boolean statement?

Tags: c++

Why and how does this code work?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void nothing()
{
    false;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Working" << endl;
    nothing();
    cout << "It worked!" << endl;
}
```

As you can see, the function definition of the function `nothing()` has nothing but a statement `false;` in it, but still it compiles and runs fine, doing nothing. How and why is this possible? Am I missing something here?

Comment: why do you think that this code is wrong? here is working code too: `1;2;3;`

Comment: @Lashane I don't think that the code is wrong, I'm just curious to know how it works, thanks btw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
false;
```

is a valid statement in C++. It doesn't do anything useful but it is still valid. Most compilers will probably remove that line from the object code they create for the function.

Some compilers, with the right compiler flags, will let you know that the statement has no effect. With `g++ --Wall`, I get:

```
socc.cc: In function ‘void nothing()’:
socc.cc:3:9: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    false;
```

Comment: Also many of them may produce warning as statement does not have any effect

Comment: @Slava, indeed.

Comment: _"Most compilers will probably remove that line from the object code they create for the function."_ I'm struggling to imagine what object code they _could_ create for the function. The line literally has no effect on the program's semantics.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, that is a symptom of my unfamiliarity with what compilers do when they create object code.

Comment: @RSahu: Well, what low-level logical instructions do you envision a computer processor performing that might be represented by this line of C++? What calculations might be involved?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, g++, when used with -S flag, creates 19 lines of assembly code for `nothing`.

Comment: @RSahu: `void nothing() { false; }` and `false;` are not the same thing. Your own answer discusses whether the statement will have an effect, not whether the function has an effect. Try to be consistent in your argumentation please; it's difficult to keep up with the fast pace at which you change what you're referring to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I mention both aspects. The first paragraph talks about what a compiler will do to the function. Second talks about what compiler will do to the line, with g++ as a sample point. I am definitely missing the essense of what you are talking about.